# ERROR: using kafka-connect-cdc-mssql:1.0.0-preview

Tags: sql-server, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

I try read the log transaction with Kafka Connector, with connector kafka-connect-cdc-mssql:1.0.0-preview

I'm using the Confluent CLI and I have already modified the configuration file:

```
etc/schema-registry/connect-avro-standalone.properties
```

I add :

```
plugin.path=/usr/share/java,/tmp/Softwares/confluent-hub-client-latest/share/confluent-hub-components/confluentinc-kafka-connect-cdc-mssql/lib
```

I have this problem: when I run the command 
$ confluent load   -d

```
$ confluent load mssqlCDC -d /tmp/Softwares/confluent-hub-client-latest/share/confluent-hub-components/confluentinc-kafka-connect-cdc-mssql/etc/mssqlsource.properties
```

I get this error message:

```
(23) Failed writing body
```

My archive mssqlsource.properties:

```
name=mssqlsource
tasks.max=2
connector.class=io.confluent.connect.cdc.mssql.MsSqlSourceConnector
initial.database=(MYDATABASE)
server.name=(MYSERVER)
server.port=(PORT)
username=(MYUSER)
password=(MYPASS)
change.tracking.tables=(MYTABLE)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `confluent load` command is actually running a `curl` command under the hood, it might be easier to run it yourself and get the proper error, convert your properties file to a `mssqlsource.json` file:

```
{
  "name": "mssqlsource",
  "config": {
    "tasks.max": 2,
    "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.cdc.mssql.MsSqlSourceConnector",
    "initial.database": "(MYDATABASE)",
    "server.name": "(MYSERVER)",
    "server.port": "(PORT)",
    "username": "(MYUSER)",
    "password": "(MYPASS)",
    "change.tracking.tables": "(MYTABLE)"
  }
}
```

And then run `curl -XPOST -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data @/path/to/mssqlsource.json connect-host:8083/connectors`

That will give you a better error message, and will be closer to a real-world example of using Kafka Connect, as the `confluent` command line is meant for local development environments.